# Custom Header and Footer using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have one blank document say 'A' and one skeleton document say 'B'. In document B i added my custom header and footer for example: Footer contains one logo and address. And my requirement is during my document A generation, I need to copy the B's header and footer contents to the A's header and footer area. B's header and footer may contain the combination of text and image. How can I accomplish this using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. If any one need further clarification please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally i found the answer to my question. I am posting the code here so in future someone will benefit with this piece of code.

```
B.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.CopyAsPicture();
A.Sections[1].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.Paste();
B.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.CopyAsPicture();
A.Sections[1].Footers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range.Paste();
```